# WSL 2, GUI Applications using XServer

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x-server

I've seen this question before, but none of the solutions are working for me.  I know the steps that are mentioned everywhere to get GUI applications working for WSL 2 on the Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview.

1. Install XServer on your windows 10 machine (here I used [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/))
2. Run the XServer
3. Install something in WSL 2 that you want to display (for me it was terminator)
4. Run `DISPLAY=:0 terminator -u` to get it running.

However, when I do number 4, I get:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
You need to run terminator in an X environment. Make sure $DISPLAY is properly set
```

When I `echo $DISPLAY` it returns `:0` as expected.

When I try to open something simple like `xclock` I get `Error: Can't open display: :0`

The X server is definitely running as I set it up and it exists in the Windows 10 system tray.  I've tried many configurations for the X server, and I get the same thing every time.  I've also tried just setting the $DISPLAY in the .bashrc file, with the same results.

I've also tried the solutions proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897846/cant-run-gtk-on-wsl-display-error), by exporting `DISPLAY` to `localhost:0.0`, which the same results (also tried 0.0, :0, and a few others).

I've tried rebooting, uninstalling and reinstalling things, and I get the same results every time.  I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4171#issuecomment-559961027 this comment about firewall rules for VcXsrv on the windows side helped me.

Answer (score -2):

You need to export your display so use:

> export DISPLAY=:0.0

Comment: I've already tried exporting DISPLAY to :0.0, localhost:0.0, and :0.  In the instructions I linked it said to export it, and in my solution I said I "set" it, but I should have said export.